# Avoiding running out of disk storage when running Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a very basic setup of Kafka where I am running a single broker instance on an AWS EC2 instance with a storage of 100GB. However, within hours I get the issue that the disk has been occupied by 100% and most of it is due to the Docker running Kafka. Here is the simple Kafka service that I am running:

```
broker:
image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.2.0
hostname: broker
container_name: broker
depends_on:
  - zookeeper
ports:
  - "9092:9092"
  - "9101:9101"
environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://<ip>:9092
  KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
  KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
  KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
  KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: <ip>
  KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
  CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
```

I suspect it might be I am not setting that retention and cleanup policy.Which I had set up by defining it as:

```
KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MINUTES: 5
KAFKA_LOG_CLEANUP_POLICY: compact, delete
```

However, when I set this up apart from facing the disk full issue, I am not able to publish any new messages to a Kafka topic.
Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: By default, Kafka stores data in `/tmp/kafka-logs`. Check if it uses the 100 GB storage. You might be writing to the root storage and leaving the 100GB unused

Comment: 1) Why not use MSK? 2) You have shown no volume mount for the container so I doubt it is using any attached EBS volume on the instance

Comment: How do we do the second part 2) You have shown no volume mount for the container so I doubt it is using any attached EBS volume on the instance

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by defining Docker volumes for my kafka setup as follows:

```
 # Create dirs for Kafka / ZK data.
mkdir -p /vol1/zk-data
mkdir -p /vol2/zk-txn-logs
mkdir -p /vol3/kafka-data

# Make sure the user has the read and write permissions.
chown -R 1000:1000 /vol1/zk-data
chown -R 1000:1000 /vol2/zk-txn-logs
chown -R 1000:1000 /vol3/kafka-data
```

Got this from the confluent documentation [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/operations/external-volumes.html#data-volumes-for-kafka-and-zk) and defined it in my docker compose file as:

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - /vol1/zk-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - /vol2/zk-txn-logs:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.2.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://ip:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: <ip>
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

    volumes:
      - /vol3/kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
```